# How to set a Auth cookie in asp.net 5

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core

Trying to make a very simple form of authentication in asp.net5 but seems like they removed the form authentication. What else could I use to make a very simple authentication?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of FormsAuthentication, it is called Cookie Authentication in ASP.NET 5. Same concepts as in Identity 2.x which I describe here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2015/02/18/evolving-asp-net-apps-cookie-authentication.aspx

There are some changes to the API in aspnet5 but this should help at least.

Comment: I suggest look at the code in SignInManager.SignInAsync https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity/SignInManager.cs#L137 which ultimately ends up calling CookieAuthenticationHandler.HandleSignInAsync https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs#L221

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
if (authUser.Username == "admin" && authUser.Password == "admin")
    {
        var claims = new[] { new Claim("name", authUser.Username), new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin") };
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        Context.Authentication.SignIn(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));

        return Redirect("~/Home/Index");
    }
```

Sample code - https://github.com/anuraj/CookieAuthMVCSample

Comment: Thanks for this response. It helped guide me in the right direction for authentication in mvc core, although you are missing some implementation details.  I found this article in the mvc core documentation that helps configure this functionality.  https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/cookie.html