# ASP.NET 5 Authentication using custom provider (Not using EF)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-authentication

I have a ASP.NET 4 project that I am upgrading to ASP.NET 5.  My authentication currently works by passing authentication requests via message queue to our backend system

How can I achieve this using the new system in ASP.NET 5? Every piece of documentation I find online seems tailored to using EF (which Im not using) or requires what seems like an absurd amount of work [such as this](https://github.com/kriasoft/AspNet-Server-Template/blob/master/src/App.Server/Data/UserStore.cs)

My system doesn't even allow users to be created, so all I need is a simple implementation for checking whether user details are valid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a Auth cookie in asp.net 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32373211/how-to-set-a-auth-cookie-in-asp-net-5)

Comment: The [ASP.NET Security](https://github.com/aspnet/Security) repo also has examples.

Comment: What do you mean by "authentication requests via message queue to our backend system"? HTTP Module/Handler?

Comment: I mean it literally send the request via RabbitMQ to a service that deals with that request.  I was trying to highlight the face that the Website has no connection to the DB whatsoever

Comment: I suspected it, but doesn't hurt to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the possibilities of how to solve this are virtually endless with ASP.NET Core. I suggest you scan the [security](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/index.html) portion to determine what you need. Based on what I know right now from your question I think you could use [Cookie Middleware](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/cookie.html) for what you want. The bit about overriding ValidateAsync:

> To implement an override for the ValidateAsync() event you must write a method with the following signature;

```
Task ValidateAsync(CookieValidatePrincipalContext context);
```

This way you can implement it any way you want. Is this usefull?