# return RedirectToAction not Functioning

Tags: asp.net-mvc, return-type

[image]

I already simple checking the name and pass(=true)

When return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); ---> not function

I don't know what wrongs! No error show

Please help.. Thx a lot.

Comment: have you put break point to that line? that line looks ok to me, I think your code never enter that if block.

Comment: @Rahul http://localhost:49972/user/~/Home/Index show... the right path is http://localhost:49972/Home/Index

Comment: @JHOng put the debugger point and check which place get an error

Comment: Do you have any attributes or security in place like [Autorize] in the Home controller or Index action?

Comment: try to add [AllowAnonymous] on redirected action just to make sure it is working or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ***is*** probably working.

However, you most likely have Cookie authentication or similar activated which means that MVC will redirect the user back to the login page since the authentication cookie cannot be found.

Before returning the redirect, you must create the cookie.

How you do that depends on which version of MVC that you are running.

Here is for MVC5:
[How to set a Auth cookie in asp.net 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32373211/how-to-set-a-auth-cookie-in-asp-net-5)

Add the following before `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");`

```
   // Which claims depends on what kind of information you want to store about the user
   var claims = new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, name) };
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    Context.Authentication.SignIn(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));
```

And a ASP.NET Core MVC example is available here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 0):

Try This Way:

LoginController.cs

```
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Web.Configuration;

        public ActionResult LoginReadData()
        {
            string query = "Select * from login where name=@name and password=@password";

            //using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnn"].ConnectionString))
                OR
            using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection("Your Connection String")) //here you need to add connection 
            {
                OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(query, connection);

                connection.Open();

                OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string name = reader[0].ToString();
                    string password = reader[1].ToString();

                    if (name != null && password != null)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return View("Create", "Registration");
                    }
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
            return View();
        }
```